# Getting a list of binary numbers composing a number

Tags: java

In Java, having a number like `0b1010`, I would like to get a list of numbers "composing" this one: `0b1000` and `0b0010` in this example: one number for each bit set.

I'm not sure about the best solution to get it. Do you have any clue ?

Comment: use bitwise operators to check if it is set in the value you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)!

```
long x = 0b101011;
BitSet bs = BitSet.valueOf(new long[]{x});
for (int i = bs.nextSetBit(0); i >=0 ; i = bs.nextSetBit(i+1)) {
    System.out.println(1 << i);
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
8
32
```

If you really want them printed out as binary strings, here's a little hack on the above method:

```
long x = 0b101011;
char[] cs = new char[bs.length()];
Arrays.fill(cs, '0');

BitSet bs = BitSet.valueOf(new long[]{x});
for (int i = bs.nextSetBit(0); i >=0 ; i = bs.nextSetBit(i+1)) {
    cs[bs.length()-i-1] = '1';
    System.out.println(new String(cs));  // or whatever you want to do with this String
    cs[bs.length()-i-1] = '0';
}
```

Output:

```
000001
000010
001000
100000
```

Comment: You can use Integer.toBinaryString() :)

Comment: D'oh! You know, I knew there had to be some method for that - looked all over `java.text` and `java.util.Formatter` and gave up. Whoops!

Answer (score 1):

Scan through the bits one by one using an AND operation. This will tell you if a bit at one position is set or not. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND). Once you have determined that some ith-Bit is set, make up a string and print it. PSEUDOCODE:

```
public static void PrintAllSubbitstrings(int number)
{
   for(int i=0; i < 32; i++) //32 bits maximum for an int
   {
        if( number & (1 << i) != 0) //the i'th bit is set.
        {
            //Make up a bitstring with (i-1) zeroes to the right, then one 1 on the left
            String bitString = "1";
            for(int j=0; j < (i-1); j++) bitString += "0";
            System.out.println(bitString);
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little test that works for me

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   int num = 0b1010;
   int testNum = 0b1;
   while(testNum < num) {
       if((testNum & num) >0) {
           System.out.println(testNum + " Passes");
       } 
       testNum *= 2;
   }
}
```